# Nested method call attached to an instance of DOMWindow instead of self

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

```
someSingleton = (function() {    
    var someFunction = function() {
        console.log(this);
        someOtherFunc();
    };

    var someOtherFunc = function() {
        console.log(this);
    };

    return {
        method: someFunction
    }
})();

someSingleton.method();
```

If run you this you'll notice the first method will return the object as expected and the second nested method call, someOtherFunction, will return the DOMWindow object.

Other than passing the instance (this) as a parameter to the second method, how do I make it so that the second method call is referencing the containing object and not DOMWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someOtherFunc.call(this);`

It depends only on how the function is called, not where or how it's defined.

Comment: Worked like a charm.. I guess I need a better understanding of call/apply.  Thanks a bunch.  I cannot vote you up since I'm new but when I can... I'll go back and vote this up

Comment: It's a closure issue. someOtherFunc still fires from the context of its origin because all you're doing is referencing it. You can still fire it in the other scope via closure reference but that doesn't change the scope that it's in. the function you're assigning to method is also a reference but its context is altered because you've assigned to an object property.

Comment: @ErikReppen `this` has nothing to do with scope or closures. It's simply determined by how you call a function.

Comment: The nature of the problem has plenty to do with scope and closures.

Comment: @ErikReppen but you said *It's a closure issue* where as `this` is never a closure issue.

Comment: If JavaScript didn't have closures .method wouldn't be able to access someOtherFunc after the parent function executed. Because someOtherFunc is referenced via closure, it's 'this' value retains it's original state. Don't tell me that's not a closure issue.

Comment: @ErikReppen You are misunderstanding `this`. It is not retained. It's always resolved anew when you call a function, for each and every call of a function everywhere. And it depends on how that call was made.

Comment: Ah, crap you're right. It only binds to the current object context if its attached as a property. I was thinking as if this was called out and captured from outside of the closure-reffed function.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the calling context of a function explicitly using the `call` method *<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call)</sup>*:

```
var someFunction = function() {
    console.log(this);
    someOtherFunc.call(this);
};
```

The faulty binding of `this` to `window` is a common JavaScript bug.

Comment: How is it a bug? It's working exactly like it's specified to work.

Comment: Not a bug. Just a yucky decision.

Comment: Well, ok. Ostensibly there's not much difference between a bug and a bad decision, or maybe it's just a bug in programmers' brains for thinking it should work any differently than it does?

Answer (score 0):

Understanding `this` in javascript can be a challenge. I can recommend 
reading [Douglas Crockford's Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) for a better understanding. Meanwhile, you can check out this link :) http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

It's quite common to assign the parent object to a variable `that`. This way, you can access it's properties and functions through it:

```
(function(){
  var that = this;
  that.someFunc = function(){};
  that.someOtherFunc = function(){
    console.log(that);
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to use a `bind` function to store the context of the method. A trivial example might look something like this:

```
someSingleton = (function() {   

    var singleton = {};

    var _bind = function (func, me) {
        return function () {
            func.apply(me, arguments);   
        }
    }

    var someFunction = _bind(function() {
        console.log(this);
        someOtherFunc();
    }, singleton);

    var someOtherFunc = _bind(function() {
        console.log(this);
    }, singleton);

    singleton.method = someFunction;

    return singleton;
})();

someSingleton.method();​
```